# Как нужно писать о мужчине-деве, если он родился в сентябре

Tags: синтаксис, склонение

- Ты такой скорпион.
- А ты такая сентябрьская дева.

Если мужчина - дева по гороскопу, родился в сентябре, будет ли корректно говорить "ты такая сентябрьская дева", потому что слова "такая" и "сентябрьская" указывают на принадлежность человека к полу, а дева - знак зодиака, на пол не указывает, он такой и есть.
В варианте, который написан вверху, не складывается ли впечатление, что речь идет о девушке? (эти предложения написаны без контекста, может все дело в нем, именно в контексте стоит указать, что мужчина - дева?)
Или лучше сказать "ты такой сентябрьская дева", или "ты такой сентябрьский дева"?

Или еще какой-то вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***А ты такой сентябрьский дева.***

В этом значении мы считаем, что существительное "дева" имеет общий род, а выбор конкретного рода (мужского или женского) делается по определению.

Сравнить: *Он такой непоседа. Она такая непоседа.*